# Why is the angular acceleration of a DC motor different according to the rotation direction in the same voltage?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I experimented with a DC motor to measure an angle, angular velocity and angular acceleration. 
The angular acceleration was differently measured according to the rotation direction, even though the absolute voltage was the same.
What makes the asymmetricity to the DC motor?

Answer (score 1):

DC motors use brushes and commutator contacts to feed electricity to the rotating armature inside the motor. Those components form a rotary switch that sequentially turns on and off successive coils of wire arrayed around the armature so the position of the energized coil is as near to perpendicular to the magnetic field produced by the permanent magnets as possible. This yields the most power and best performance possible for that motor.

Now note that for smooth power and to guarantee that there is no "ambiguous" armature position where no coils are energized, there is a bit of built-in offset between the commutator contacts and the brush position which means that the switch timing depends on which way the motor is rotating.

This in turn means that the motor makes more power and hence spins faster in one direction than the other. This means that even though the motor is at least in principle fully reversible by reversing the power polarity, it spins slower "in reverse" and the proper polarity  (+ and -) will be marked on the end of the motor casing where the electrical contacts are.